# Как узнать, с какого элемента был сделан клик?

Tags: jquery, html, события, form

Здравствуйте!

В коде есть много кнопок перехода на форму вида:

```
<a href="#callback" class="fancybox"><img src="images/order.jpg" alt="alt" /></a>
...
<div class="hidden">
        <form id="callback" class="pop_form">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="order-input" id="inp-1" placeholder="Ваше имя" required /><br />
            <input type="text" name="phone" class="order-input" id="inp-2" placeholder="+375 29 *** ** **" required />
            <button class="test-drive" type="submit"></button>
        </form>
</div>
```

С кнопки button я отправляю данные на почту. Подскажите, как узнать, с какого элемента был сделан клик?

Comment: @alex_uni, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @alex_uni, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Форматируй код.
Есть свойство `event.target` - вернёт элемент, по которому произвели действие.

Comment: Да, знаю - а как его связать с формой? Если поместить в обработчик события button, то возвращается id кнопки, а не ссылки.

Comment: Не понял цель.  
Что связать? Для чего?

Comment: Сам разобрался - нужно в переменную сохранить event.target.id перехода и внутри обработчика button с помощью switch-case эту конструкцию проверять.
Вопрос снят.